# Why is methodExit is also executing multiple times - please explain the flow of this code

Tags: recursion

After running this code method1 is executing 11 times which is understood but why methodExit is running 10 times as according to me method1 should run 10 time but after return it should go to methodExit and just run it one time. Please explain

Code:

```
public class demo {
    static int temp=0;

    static void methodExit() {

        System.out.println("  method exit executed "+temp);
        temp++;
    }
    static void method1()
    {
        System.out.print(" "+temp);
        temp++; 

        if(temp==11)
            {
                temp=0;
                return;
            }

        method1();
        methodExit();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        method1();
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
  method exit executed 0
  method exit executed 1
  method exit executed 2
  method exit executed 3
  method exit executed 4
  method exit executed 5
  method exit executed 6
  method exit executed 7
  method exit executed 8
  method exit executed 9
```

Comment: Is that Java? You should tag the language as well

Comment: If `temp==11` then method1 does not call methodExit. All other times every call to method1 will also result in a call to methodExit.

Comment: if that's the case then why method1 is first executed till the end then methodexit starts @Thilo

Comment: Because `methodExit()` is called after `method1()`. So `method1` completes (including all recursive calls to more`method1`) before `methodExit()` is called. I recommend you visualize the call sequence on a piece of paper or step through in a debugger.